# problem install ubuntu through windows store

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to test Ubuntu way Windows store but I had this problem:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note: Ubuntu is now available from the Windows Store for users running Windows 10 x64 Insiders build > 16215 with the WSL optional component enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The message in the screen image says that you need a newer version of Windows 10.

You can [download Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and using the instructions on that website, create a live USB from which you can try Ubuntu, or install Ubuntu on your system.

Comment: yes I use Ubuntu an another distros in double-boot form.. but I want to try with this form , I understand thar ubuntu works in a sandbox .. How I can upgrade my windows to later version .. There any way without pay?

Comment: You would have to ask Microsoft about that